# Ошибка access violation

Tags: delphi

Запускаю программу, нажимаю кнопку и появляется ошибка -

> access violation at address in module project1.exe. read of address FFFFFFFF

На форме кнопка и код:

```
Var
 I,First:Integer;
 SLInS,S:String;
 SLIn,SLOut:TStringList;

 DictionaryArray: TArray<TPair<string, integer>>;
 DictionaryArrayItem: TPair<string, integer>;

 Dictionary : TDictionary<String,Integer>;
begin
  First:=4;

  Dictionary:= TDictionary<String,Integer>.Create;

  SLOut:=TStringList.Create;

  SLIn:=TStringList.Create;
  SLIn.LoadFromFile('Out.txt');
  SLIn.Delimiter:=' ';
  SLIn.DelimitedText:=SLIn.Text;

    For I:=0 to slIn.Count-1 do
      Begin
        SLInS:=slIn.Strings[I];
          if Pos(':',SLInS)<>0 Then delete(SLInS,1,Pos(':',SLInS));

          If Dictionary.ContainsKey(SLInS) then Dictionary[SLInS]:=Dictionary[SLInS]+1
          Else Dictionary.Add(SLInS,1);
      End;


  DictionaryArray := Dictionary.ToArray;

  TArray.Sort<TPair<string, integer>>(
    DictionaryArray, TComparer<TPair<string, integer>>.Construct(
      function (const Left, Right: TPair<string, integer>): Integer
      begin
        Result := CompareStr(Left.Value.ToString, Right.Value.ToString);
        if Result = 0 then
          Result := CompareStr(Left.Key, Right.Key);
      end));


      for I :=Length(DictionaryArray)-1 downto Length(DictionaryArray)-First do
       SLOut.add(Format('%s: %s',[DictionaryArray[I].Key,DictionaryArray[I].Value.ToString]));

  SLOut.SaveToFile('REZ.txt');

  Dictionary.Free;
  SLIn.Free;
  SLOut.Free;
end;
```

**Нажимаю на кнопку - Break, что бы узнать где ошибка:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Далее меня перебрасывает на модуль System.SysUtils:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**И потом:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что произойдёт в этой строчке  при малой длине массива? `for I :=Length(DictionaryArray)-1 downto Length(DictionaryArray)-First`

Comment: Странный у вас цикл от "длина массива-1" до "длина массива-4(First)". Вам не кажется, что количество итераций не зависит от "длины массива"? Ну а если "длина массива" меньше First, то цикл пойдет в отрицательные индексы  элементов массива. А они у Вас есть? Полагаю элемента с индексом -1, -2 и т.д. Нету. Оттуда и ошибка доступа.

Comment: Мне кажется что то не то с обращением к элементу массива в последнем цикле. Проверьте в отладке `DictionaryArray[I]`.